# Cordova / PhoneGap barcode scanner crashes after 9 open / cancel with "out of memory" on 5s

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, barcode-scanner, cordova-plugins

Using the BarcodeDemo Cordova app at:

https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeDemo.git

I tap the scan link and wait for the scanner to open and then I tap the cancel button. I do this 9 times and the app crashes with an "out of memory" message in xcode. Every time I tap open it takes a little longer for scanner to appear until it finally crashes. This is the exact behavior I get in my own app with the same barcode scanner plugin.

This only happens on my iPhone 5s with ios version 7.0.4. It works fine on a iPhone 4s with ios 7.1.1.

What do I need to do to solve this problem ?

**Here is the xcode console output:**

```
2014-11-21 15:17:25.517 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.7.0 is starting.
2014-11-21 15:17:25.522 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-11-21 15:17:25.527 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-11-21 15:17:25.531 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful.
Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data.
For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at:
https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/
To disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file

2014-11-21 15:17:26.735 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-11-21 15:17:26.863 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/0FBDB3C8-A197-476F-9DF3-30AF29418562/BarcodeDemo.app/www/index.html
2014-11-21 15:17:39.422 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x70223940> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
2014-11-21 15:17:39.424 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x70223940> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:17:39.470 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x70223940> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:17:47.905 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x702296a0> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
2014-11-21 15:17:47.907 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x702296a0> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:17:47.927 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x702296a0> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:17:53.539 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x78036220> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
2014-11-21 15:17:53.539 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x78036220> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:17:53.547 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x78036220> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:17:57.794 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x702396a0> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
2014-11-21 15:17:57.795 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x702396a0> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:17:57.802 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x702396a0> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:18:01.965 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x78234d00> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
2014-11-21 15:18:01.966 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x78234d00> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:18:01.973 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x78234d00> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:18:06.867 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x78c31680> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
2014-11-21 15:18:06.868 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x78c31680> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:18:06.875 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x78c31680> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:18:25.036 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x7502f320> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
2014-11-21 15:18:25.038 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x7502f320> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:18:25.058 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x7502f320> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:18:38.912 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:18:48.917 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:18:58.925 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:19:08.931 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:19:18.937 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:19:28.946 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:19:38.951 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:19:48.955 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:19:58.964 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:20:08.970 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:20:18.976 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:20:31.101 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:didFirstLayoutInFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:20:41.107 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:didFirstLayoutInFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:20:51.112 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:didFirstLayoutInFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:20:58.664 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x63f9a800> isOrientationSupported] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -isVideoOrientationSupported
2014-11-21 15:20:58.666 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x63f9a800> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:20:58.683 BarcodeDemo[1984:60b] WARNING: -[<AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x63f9a800> setOrientation:] is deprecated.  Please use AVCaptureConnection's -setVideoOrientation:
2014-11-21 15:21:18.645 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:21:28.650 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:21:38.656 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:21:48.661 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:21:58.667 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:22:08.674 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:22:18.680 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:22:28.686 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:22:38.695 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:22:48.701 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:22:58.707 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:23:08.714 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:23:18.720 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:23:28.731 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:23:38.737 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2014-11-21 15:23:48.743 BarcodeDemo[1984:4703] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
```

**And Here is the crash log:**

```
Incident Identifier: 067161C3-8723-4962-96F2-E92522A4183B
CrashReporter Key:   b01f29f7e8735a90ebb94368c74dbe23afcc1444
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
OS Version:          iPhone OS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Kernel Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 14.0.0: Fri Sep 27 23:08:32 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2423.3.12~1/RELEASE_ARM64_S5L8960X
Date:                2014-11-21 15:23:52 -0800
Time since snapshot: 290 ms

Free pages:                              2196
Active pages:                            133705
Inactive pages:                          66718
Speculative pages:                       2
Throttled pages:                         0
Purgeable pages:                         45
Wired pages:                             31912
File-backed pages:                       25634
Anonymous pages:                         174791
Compressions:                            461810
Decompressions:                          124200
Compressor Size:                         21205
Uncompressed Pages in Compressor:        54697
Largest process:   BarcodeDemo

Processes
     Name                    <UUID>                       rpages       recent_max   fds      [reason]          (state)

        BlueTool <3e33895f890b36c3b53e85553d4fbcae>          128              128  100                      (daemon) (idle)
softwarebehavior <7690038b358c37898302319ca3399f9d>          157              157   50                      (daemon) (idle)
AppleIDAuthAgent <751b6effdac33accbc1ee71340f13f83>          163              163   50                      (daemon) (idle)
            adid <923c299ca14d340bbfb1fc82b7128bbc>          128              128  200                      (daemon) (idle)
com.apple.facebo <6ccd695caf3f37ee87c2a95b78ffd650>          349              349  200                      (daemon) (idle)
          oscard <2c878b7a36a7385f83d697630814786d>          119              119  200                      (daemon) (idle)
com.apple.Mobile <d1e1974a010f323bab65fcac29fa6d13>          148              148  100                      (daemon) (idle)
        recentsd <8b6394bd9dfa3c6bbfcbe35b2c26e79c>          343              343  200                      (daemon) (idle)
com.apple.Stream <750dc669e6b93f308b3eadecc452c2f5>          173              173  200                      (daemon) (idle)
com.apple.Mobile <f6dd5a11ccd33a9f9b74a5a59b6b6276>         2036             2036  200                      (daemon) (idle)
AGXCompilerServi <3e8f0c21acac3decbc30ff91dbaaf705>          579              579  200                      (daemon) (idle)
    mediaremoted <4734e15435133a48bdba8714c6b14782>          326              326  100                      (daemon) (idle)
    CMFSyncAgent <9242105b8bf93ff4b9f2266cb6188c6c>          177              177  200                      (daemon) (idle)
IMDPersistenceAg <8273fba29a743c50a3fe5935d907f064>         1280             1280  100                      (daemon) (idle)
coresymbolicatio <1fcfe2583ae43349b750cb1fb27f6b55>           87               87  200                      (daemon) (idle)
limitadtrackingd <22983e0098af3cc58e40a549b84fc87c>          332              332  200                      (daemon) (idle)
   webbookmarksd <b4d002aa6c9732cb8ff8a34b3d066ebb>          554              554  200                      (daemon) (idle)
         keybagd <191646aacbae3062b8471689120d732b>          128              128  100                      (daemon) (idle)
            afcd <bedf923b9619380681a8a4c58ef25afe>          130              130  200                      (daemon) (idle)
      librariand <f9e63967978833b585958d2d38f51e16>          235              235  200                      (daemon) (idle)
         deleted <80aa63406a9a3d13be49a01f59737e03>          755              755  200                      (daemon) (idle)
mobile_assertion <d1d96a7e27523acfb24537d1a6f79a68>          123              123  200                      (daemon) (idle)
 softwareupdated <b4d53c71a23e35eca1fe42bc817eb665>          166              166  100                      (daemon) (idle)
            geod <11b3b01893863c0a98149a6b3cab0be9>          658              658  200                      (daemon) (idle)
softwareupdatese <de50780fadc1346cb098360fbc076ee8>         2009             2009  200                      (daemon) (idle)
storebookkeeperd <bd3e55b901c030a28e0849ba58f27cd6>         1133             1133  100                      (daemon) (idle)
    itunescloudd <b5212676352c3730a6790fc982cb9c27>         1396             1396  100                      (daemon) (idle)
         assetsd <b7c33bea37d13263bd6196f656b0bceb>         1777             1777  200                      (daemon) (idle)
   medialibraryd <dce561c3a2ea3b8682f4e1ab1bc2166b>          600              600  200                      (daemon) (idle)
            xpcd <140b5ddf31003794a1508a7bd32df86f>          268              268  100                      (daemon) (idle)
MobileGestaltHel <b783dda7a2a0327c93d85a7d94c93add>          165              165  100                      (daemon) (idle)
CloudKeychainPro <90dbeb05578f3e0bbd1565b73a90dce7>          145              145  200                      (daemon) (idle)
            afcd <bedf923b9619380681a8a4c58ef25afe>          128              128  200                      (daemon) (idle)
      aosnotifyd <9b707eee605b3ed79e659aec0c96172c>          400              400   50                      (daemon) (idle)
        installd <168414caa0da34ed9b5f4bc5348f0a6a>          843              843   50                      (daemon) (idle)
mobile_installat <505940b97aae31e5bdcfe142e3a00936>          823              823  200                      (daemon) (idle)
       accountsd <cb88b321caea305b819c78861c81b0c0>          853              853  100                      (daemon) (idle)
    itunesstored <0d023473a4a93c93a531210de784b155>         2255             2255  100                      (daemon) (idle)
        sandboxd <c084e37b88df32c6ae3f21516eb4803b>          133              133  100                      (daemon) (idle)
     Preferences <f22b47d23063334ca94a83d88ca9c94d>         2758             2758  200                      (suspended)
         DuetLST <a8ba1e6da6bd390fb155000022a963eb>          843              843  200                      (daemon) (idle)
       securityd <14da750b1c9230c9a67c0518bc742e48>          664              664  100                      (daemon) (idle)
            xpcd <140b5ddf31003794a1508a7bd32df86f>          371              371  100                      (daemon) (idle)
             lsd <1abde6d1af42396bbf166cc9e37ba914>         1210             1210  100                      (daemon) (idle)
AGXCompilerServi <3e8f0c21acac3decbc30ff91dbaaf705>          613              613  200                      (daemon) (idle)
           timed <b75e87ae63123c45967d4355a43622bd>          276              276   50                      (daemon) (idle)
networkd_privile <ded764728f4d3166b5dcf2682afc97a8>           92               92  100                      (daemon) (idle)
   wirelessproxd <9f112d11a5f734019013a43e9fc677a9>          198              198   50                      (daemon) (idle)
        routined <0bffecf27c643f6097a6f4c6f4750792>          788              788   50                      (daemon) (idle)
      MobileMail <387c38c23acc32dc912a5088ef6b2b66>         1300             1300  200                      (resume) (continuous)
            tccd <a4190e0e6f6b3d23b06326c8935a5bb4>          210              210  200                      (daemon)
             kbd <4350c1efc23b3182809fcb6d8a7885fd>         1691             1691  200                      (daemon)
     MobilePhone <c4ca225b8be13733a52c6695f1e269cc>         2768             2768  200                      (continuous)
     BarcodeDemo <a08c1a625ead310b9bc19b76fc2f112d>       166400           166400  200  [per-process-limit] (frontmost) (resume)
            ptpd <872030b325d9383b95a5434d41f77b25>         1186             1186  200                      (daemon)
identityservices <cd1fff47d6ad3b0f85cdc5fb39d8b53e>          761              761  100                      (daemon)
         syslogd <5c3a246617d3399e977efc84c2e29df2>          942              942   50                      (daemon)
       locationd <10f268a18d5d3343ab21be48bb005ecf>         2437             2437  100                      (daemon)
          powerd <a1fc82c399dc36e2b18a6fbb3d936a88>          155              155  100                      (daemon)
         imagent <5080234127f5363fb539ffc3965af6e2>         1183             1183   50                      (daemon)
           wifid <ca4f06468bf03d0f8847089e8cd320f1>          815              815   50                      (daemon)
             vmd <19de7c691b3137fea83e23261df6802a>          588              588   50                      (daemon)
    mediaserverd <f067d4c2a21a30fbabab30d9c94ccbd3>         5381             5381   50                      (daemon)
   iaptransportd <4c622f6c4295395997e7a6ec783b4623>          260              260  100                      (daemon)
   mDNSResponder <2b8ad561938f3fc0a6255b607f503040>          300              300  100                      (daemon)
            apsd <ceb7855af3a63c2682fab13d5e0aeb82>          785              785  100                      (daemon)
     dataaccessd <b155854105f531248c2a44fd3733d59e>         1280             1280  200                      (daemon)
        sharingd <550630f3f5dc3f0aa08ba04876d82e6d>          601              601   50                      (daemon)
    mobileassetd <b7dae5ed4ac938fabd5f8fa28834e2f4>         1936             1936  200                      (daemon)
      calaccessd <d6960604dc2c37499cd597b510055d7e>          537              537  200                      (daemon)
    syslog_relay <773c693446c6346f9aa3fa3b56388ffb>          115              115  200                      (daemon)
     SpringBoard <fe632b47e4ee342baf4b3701cd11b242>         6404             6404  200                     
      backboardd <2f84882cf3693dfb921f4e0d38966f50>         9491             9491   50                      (daemon)
         configd <bb6e02e801a93ef896f2f3cf5cbb00fe>          776              776   50                      (daemon)
       lockdownd <e280cf66209e3be980809a7d93eea76e>          349              349   50                      (daemon)
       fseventsd <a0223d346d4431a5ba1caabf8505b40e>         2134             2134   50                      (daemon)
    fairplayd.H2 <da123871e48a3b6a9a2998f428e5c05a>          143              143  100                      (daemon)
      aggregated <6189b3e3d0c83a879b99cf7cd566dffb>         1117             1117  100                      (daemon)
        BTServer <3669aefbfb2e3577b17bde9598feda76>          350              350  100                      (daemon)
       distnoted <c40569cbea09312b9310bc74cbc88e29>          163              163  100                      (daemon)
  UserEventAgent <0d33b64c0c003a65b9a87c6622921781>          782              782  100                      (daemon)
        networkd <c7aa87e0c2d33d379a09598281a5e3ee>          651              651  100                      (daemon)
   biometrickitd <96a562b32d2f3ae0b3d23706c2f5d5ac>          271              271  200                      (daemon)
filecoordination <72a4cec360d435c09cb83d2316317288>          228              228  200                      (daemon)
EscrowSecurityAl <e14ee8c5bc0f3447b6cdaad44ab402da>          221              221  200                      (daemon)
         DTPower <dbfa952ac40833d58cb1ad5e3c48099e>          278              278  200                      (daemon)
notification_pro <72244e97bc7d33408cd01f8c7fb7d2eb>          124              124  200                      (daemon)
     touchsetupd <0c315f01ae8d3675ad1a4eda4c9b18bb>          207              207  200                      (daemon)
     debugserver <756146181af631a9b08c7e3c8525c41d>          185              185  200                      (daemon)
          cplogd <96828e7047bf36e2a1cdffcc1be700f8>          139              139  200                      (daemon)
      CommCenter <ba4a2aecbe913f0ca31c8902e444db0d>         1693             1693  100                      (daemon)
         notifyd <bd919e93d6293562af0b7ec0e21247a0>          293              293  100                      (daemon)
```

**End**

Comment: Right. But you could have formatted it at least

Comment: Warren, I have to agree with sha: It's not difficult to make your question eminently more readable. @sha, you can edit the question instead of posting snarky comments.